# Simple NSPageController example throws an unknown subview warning and stops working

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm trying to get a very basic NSPageController to work (in book mode, not history mode). It will successfully transition once, and then stop working.

I suspect I'm creating the NSImageViews I'm loading into it wrong, but I can't figure out how.

The storyboard has a the SamplePageController which holds in initial hard-coded NSImageView.

I suspect I'm missing something really obvious here, since all of the tutorial's I've found for NSPageController are in Objective C not swift, and tend to focus on the history view mode.

The code is:

```
import Cocoa

class SamplePageController: NSPageController, NSPageControllerDelegate {

    private var images = [NSImage]()
    @IBOutlet weak var Image: NSImageView!

    //Gets an object from arranged objects
    func pageController(pageController: NSPageController, identifierForObject object: AnyObject) -> String {
        let image = object as! NSImage
        let image_name = image.name()!
        let temp = arrangedObjects.indexOf({$0.name == image_name})
        return "\(temp!)"
    }

    func pageController(pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSViewController {
        let controller = NSViewController()
        let imageView = NSImageView(frame: Image.frame)
        let intid = Int(identifier)
        let intid_u = intid!
        imageView.image = images[intid_u]
        imageView.sizeToFit()
        controller.view = imageView
        return controller
        // Does this eventually lose the frame since we're returning the new view and then not storing it and the original ImageView is long gone by then?
        // Alternatively, are we not sizing the imageView appropriately?
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        images.append(NSImage(named:"text")!)
        images.append(NSImage(named:"text-2")!)
        arrangedObjects = images
        delegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your `pageController.view` is set to your `window.contentView` and that triggers the warning. What you need to do is add a subview in the `window.contentView` and have your `pageController.view` point to that instead.

The reason for the warning is that since `NSPageController` creates snapshots (views) of your content history, it will add them at the same level as your `pageController.view` to transition between them: that means it will try to add them to `pageController.view.superview`.

And if your `pageController.view` is set to `window.contentView`, you are adding subviews to the `window.contentView.superview`, which is [not supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_10Window):

> New since WWDC seed: NSWindow has never supported clients adding subviews to anything other than the contentView.
>
> Some applications would add subviews to the contentView.superview (also known as the border view of the window). NSWindow will now log when it detects this scenario: "NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview:".
>
> Applications doing this will need to fix this problem, as it prevents new features on 10.10 from working properly. See titlebarAccessoryViewControllers for official API.